# Creating a 'thermal image' using data points

Tags: javascript, css, dictionary, data-representation

I am looking for a way to represent some data points into a 'thermal map' (500x500).

Data array:

```
"data": [
    {
       "x": 120,
       "y": 350,
       "temperature": 90
    },
    {
       "x": 300,
       "y": 210,
       "temperature": 35
    },
    {
       "x": 450,
       "y": 50,
       "temperature": 68
    },
]
```

This array should be processed into something like this using CSS and Javascript: (Very roughly)

[image: Rough sketch of the desired result]

**What would be the best way to approach this using Javascript and CSS?**

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're happy to help with specific issues but we're not a code writing service. Perhaps review the checklist: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To draw circles with gradient translucency, use [radial gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient).
- To position them, use `position: absolute` and `left: x`, `top: y` (make sure to omit the radius).

Knowing these two CSS features, you can just iterate over the JSON, creating DOM–elements (`div` will do) and modifying their `style` property.

Schematically:

```
data.forEach(function (point) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.background = generateGradient(point.temperature);
    div.style.left = point.x - radius;
    div.style.top = point.y - radius;
    container.appendChild(div);
});
```

The same is achievable with Canvas and SVG, but that's a longer story.

Comment: Thanks, the radial gradients is exactly what i'm looking for!