# Dynamic thermal image using CSS?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, svg-animate, data-representation

I have an illustration made by an illustrator.
This is a static thermal image with 6 particular points that I would like to animate (according to the temperature obviously).

[image: Static thermal image]

For example, I would update a JSON file and according to this file, the image would update itself :

```
{
  "sensors": [
    {
      "name": "top",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "middle",
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "bottom",
      "value": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

It would also need to update the legend beside the image (not showed).

Something like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4r916P4oyI), but with a much higher quality result.

I was thinking about doing it in CSS but I don't know how to deal with custom shape to have because the illustration is not square and radial-gradient ([like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169337/creating-a-thermal-image-using-data-points)) doesn't look beautiful when rendered on the image.

Any other technical solutions I might look into ?

Answer (score 1):

IMO you best options are:

- Use SVG, which is Scalable Vector Graphics format for two-dimensional graphics with support for interactivity and animation. Use JavaScript for dynamically change your illustrator; you could also have a look at [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap) for animations or [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) for data driven visualization.
- Use HTML5 Canvas,  which is used to draw graphics dynamically via JavaScript (in bitmap format).

In this specific case CSS is not up to the job IMO, as designing complex multi points shapes is not really its use case.